# Getting this error when installing Cocoapods

Tags: ruby

I am having an issue trying cocoapods. 
`Last login: Sat Mar 26 20:17:39 on console
Brians-MacBook-Air:~ katypatterson$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
Brians-MacBook-Air:~ katypatterson$`
Do I have install Ruby version 2.2.2 ?

Comment: I fixed it. Had to install Ruby.

Comment: I am having the same issue could you tell me how you installed ruby

Answer (score 0):

First you need install active script :

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score -1):

**installing ruby**

in terminal write the commands below:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```